# FULL OUTER JOIN no me arroja NULLs donde la key no tiene match(SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Tengo dos tablas, como ejemplo, TABLA1:

```
Cuenta      Fecha   Valor
```

```
1           201801  a    
1           201802  b
1           201803  c
1           201804  d
2           201801  f
2           201802  g
2           201803  h
```

y la TABLA2:

```
Cuenta      Fecha   Valor
```

```
1           201803  f    
1           201804  d
1           201805  s
1           201806  f
2           201801  g
2           201802  s
2           201803  a
```

---

Luego hago la siguiente Query:

```
select tabla1.cuenta as cuenta_t1,
       ,tabla1.fecha as fecha_t1
       ,tabla2.cuenta as cuenta_t2
       ,tabla2.fecha as fecha_t2
from tabla1 as tabla1
full outer join tabla2 as tabla2
on tabla1.cuenta=tabla2.cuenta and tabla1.fecha=tabla2.fecha
where tabla1.cuenta = '1'
```

Me interesa mirar solo la cuenta 1 (en realidad la tabla que tengo es más complicada que este ejemplo de juguete, por eso solo miro cuenta 1)... el resultado es el siguiente,

```
Cuenta_t1   Fecha_t1   Cuenta_t2   Fecha_t2
```

```
 1           201801     NULL       NULL    
 1           201802     NULL       NULL
 1           201803     1          201803
 1           201804     1          201804
```

---

Cuando el resultado que espero es:

```
Cuenta_t1   Fecha_t1   Cuenta_t2   Fecha_t2
```

```
 1           201801     NULL       NULL    
 1           201802     NULL       NULL
 1           201803     1          201803
 1           201804     1          201804
 NULL        NULL       1          201805
 NULL        NULL       1          201806
```

---

¿Qué está pasando con el full outer join?
Intercambiando el orden en el que elijo las tablas no altera el resultado. Al parecer sólo me entrega un numero de filas igual al mayor numero de filas entre las dos tablas.

Agradecería la ayuda de esta comunidad,

Saludos.

Comment: Es porque los valores **NULL** para **Cuenta_t1** los estas descartando con el `where tabla1.cuenta = ‘1’` ya que solo te quedas con valor 1 para esa columna

Comment: tienes razón! ahora si puedo ver como quiero la tabla cambiando la condición por `where coalesce(tabla1.cuenta,tabla2.cuenta) = '1'`. No había reparado en ese detalle, pensé que me entendería la query. GRACIAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quitas el `where tabla1.cuenta = '1'` te traera los `NULL`. tu `where` solo condiciona a 1 valor de la tabla, dejando fuera a los otros que contienen valor `NULL`.

[IMAGEN EXPLICATIVA 'JOIN'](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/SQL_Joins.svg)

Comment: Si gracias! no reparé en ese detalle, cambié la condición por `where coalesce(tabla1.cuenta,tabla2.cuenta) = '1'` y todo bien! Gracias!